# How to get the new point by which I rotate an object around (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, rotation

The idea is very simple but I cannot seem to understand how to implement it. I linked this image to better understand what I am talking about : https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aj2J.jpg. I am trying to find out the new pivot I will rotate a car around. I am using OpenGL and I have calculated myself the coordinates of where my car should be after I rotate it around a fixed pivot by alfa degrees like in the image. I have used matrix multiplication like this:

(1 0 0 x ) ( c  0  s  0) (1 0 0 -x )

(0 1 0 y ) ( 0  1  0  0) (0 1 0 -y )

(0 0 1 z ) (-s  0  c  0) (0 0 1 -z )

(0 0 0 1 ) ( 0  0  0  1) (0 0 0 1 )

to find the Transformation Matrix of the movement I am making. I know that if I have :

```
glTranslatef(xTemp,0,zTemp+R);  //T1
glRotatef(directie,0,1,0);      //R
glTranslatef(-xTemp,0,-zTemp-R); //T2
```

for steering left I would need to multiply T2 * R * T1.

Example of scenario : After I have made a left turn 90* ( like in the image) and I want to make a right turn afterwards from the point I have arrived at ( R ) how can I find the coordinates of the new pivot point ? I know that I have to somehow change the origin to be exactly where my object is after the first rotation but I am stuck here. 
P.S. The angle is not going to be always 90 degrees.

I will post the relevant code below :

```
void renderScene( void ) {

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(cameraX,cameraY,cameraZ,lookAtX,0,lookAtZ,upX, upY, upZ);


  glPushMatrix();

    if (steerLeft){
        glTranslatef(xTemp,0,zTemp+R); //xTemp,zTemp coordinates for the car before rotation
        glRotatef(angle,0,1,0);
        glTranslatef(-xTemp,0,-zTemp-R);    
    }
    else 
          if (steerRight){  
            glTranslatef(-xTemp,0,-zTemp-R);
            glRotatef(angle,0,1,0);
            glTranslatef(xTemp,0,zTemp+R);
          }
          else{ 
            glRotatef(angle,0,1,0);  //leave car in the rotated position
            glTranslatef(x1,0,z1);
        }
    glutWireCube(1);  // here I would draw my car, tires so that all the components are moved at the same time

  glPopMatrix(); 

  keyOperations(); //movement

  glutSwapBuffers();
}


void posL(GLdouble xTemp ,GLdouble y,GLdouble zTemp, GLdouble alfa ){ //used for testing to make sure the resulting coordinates are correct
    GLdouble pos[3];
    pos[1]=0;
    pos[0]= (zTemp)*sin(alfa*PI/180) +xTemp-(zTemp+R)*sin(alfa*PI/180);
    pos[2]=(zTemp)*cos(alfa*PI/180)+ (zTemp+R) - (zTemp+R)*cos(alfa*PI/180);

    // printf("x:%.2lf y:%.2lf z:%.2lf \n  ",pos[0],pos[1],pos[2]);
} //for left rotations  ( +angle  and zTemp+R )


 void posR(GLdouble xTemp ,GLdouble y,GLdouble zTemp, GLdouble alfa ){ //used for testing to make sure the resulting coordinates are correct
    GLdouble pos[3];
    pos[1]=0;
    pos[0]= (zTemp)*sin(-alfa*PI/180) +xTemp-(zTemp-R)*sin(-alfa*PI/180);
    pos[2]=(zTemp)*cos(-alfa*PI/180)+ (zTemp+R) - (zTemp-R)*cos(-alfa*PI/180);

    // printf("x:%.2lf y:%.2lf z:%.2lf \n  ",pos[0],pos[1],pos[2]);
} // for right rotations ( -angle  and zTemp-R )

void keyPressed(unsigned char key, int x, int y){
    keyStates[key]=true;
}

void keyUp(unsigned char key,int x, int y){
    keyStates[key]=false;
}

void keyOperations (void) {         

    if (keyStates['w']) { 
            if ((!keyStates['a'])&&(!keyStates['d'])){ //only moving forward

                //pos(0,0,0,90); test new coordinates for car after rotaion
                x1-=0.05;
                xTemp=x1; //stores current car position

                steerRight=false;
                steerLeft=false;
            }
    }  

    if (keyStates['s']) {
            if ((!keyStates['a'])&&(!keyStates['d'])){
                x1+=0.05;
                xTemp=x1;

                steerRight=false;
                steerLeft=false;
            }
    }  

    if ((keyStates['w']) && (keyStates['d'])) {
            steerRight=true;
            angle-=1;
    }

    if ((keyStates['w']) && (keyStates['a'])) {
            steerLeft=true;
            angle+=1;
            //printf("looking at: x:%.2lf z:%.2lf\n",x1,z1);
            x1= (zTemp)*sin(angle*PI/180) +xTemp-(zTemp+R)*sin(angle*PI/180);
            z1=(zTemp)*cos(angle*PI/180)+ (zTemp+R) - (zTemp+R)*cos(angle*PI/180);
    }

    if ((keyStates['s']) && (keyStates['d'])) {

            steerRight=true;
            sensMasina-=3;

            angle+=1;
    }

    if ((keyStates['s']) && (keyStates['a'])) {

            steerLeft=true;
            angle-=1;       
    }
}
```

Things that work :

- moving forward/backwards
- steering left/right from the origin (0,0,0)

Things that DO NOT work :

- continue movement after steering from the point arrived at

So in conclusion my questions would be :

**1. How do I set my car to be the origin for rotations whenever I want it to steer R/L, such that I can easily compute my pivot point like (xTemp,0,zTemp+R)?**

**2. Do I need to have the angle variable reset at any point in my movements?**

**3. How could I write my Push Pop Matrix operations differently so that I can "save" the position of my car at any step and so it would know where to start the new transformations from ?**